# How to narrow down the scope of a computer science research project?

Tags: computer-science, research-topic

I'm working on a CS systems project for a while where I don't seem to find the right scope so that it turns into a research question that can be answered.

I either develop the project further which improves the performance but its rather a development advancement than a insightful research contribution. But when I try to frame a research question around the system, it is so vague that I cannot seem to connect it to the system I built.

Are there any approaches to find more concrete research questions in a structured way?

Comment: Does your advisor have any useful suggestions? This is the kind of thing where you can really benefit from personal advice from someone familiar with your specific project, until you gain more experience and can do it yourself.

Comment: If your advisor has not been so helpful in this regard (which I suspect based on [this question of yours](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66736/what-can-i-do-to-convince-my-advisor-of-my-ideas)), maybe you can identify other mentors (faculty in your department, senior PhD students, etc) who could help you develop this skill.